# Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/css'

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js, react-swiper

Swiper 7.0.5 swiper/css gives error Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/css'

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';
function Test() {
 return (
  <Swiper
  spaceBetween={50}
  slidesPerView={3}
  onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
  onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
>
  <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
  <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
  ...
</Swiper>
);
}

 export default Test;
```

Comment: You did run npm i swiper or yarn add swiper, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"swiper": "^8.0.2" version, how I solved it

```
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css';
```

Other csss used to clone the demo.

```
import 'swiper/modules/free-mode/free-mode.min.css';
import 'swiper/modules/navigation/navigation.scss';
import 'swiper/modules/thumbs/thumbs.min.css';
```

If css files are not allowed to be imported individually, try adding them to the top root paths such as index.jsx.

```
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
```

Comment: its not working, still giving same error

Answer (score 44):

For `swiper@7.3.1`, the imports in a Create-React-App project work this way -

```
import React from 'react'
import { Pagination } from 'swiper'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react/swiper-react'



import 'swiper/swiper.min.css'
import 'swiper/modules/pagination/pagination.min.css'
```

Comment: be blessed among front-end devs! Amen!

Comment: been going around the git issues but end up this one the solution I need! Thank you!

Comment: Its not working for me :/

Comment: are you using swiper@7.3.1 and a Create-React-App?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. This also worked with swiper 8.4.5 for me

Comment: import 'swiper/modules/pagination/pagination.min.css' is not working for me

Answer (score 30):

after a whole day looking, I finally fixed it.
remove swiper entirely and add version 6.8.4:
npm:

```
npm install swiper@6.8.4
```

yarn:

```
yarn add swiper@6.8.4
```

then add this layout to your file and it should work:

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css'
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css'

<Swiper
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
      centeredSlides
      onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
      onSwiper={swiper => console.log(swiper)}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
```

version 6.8.4 documentation is [here](https://swiper6.vercel.app/swiper-api)

Comment: Thanks for this. I thought I was going crazy. The Swiper 7 docs explicitly said to do it as OP said and it's all broken

Comment: Thanks man, worked. their docs needs some refinement!

Comment: Can someone explain why this works?

Answer (score 7):

try this

```js
 import 'swiper/swiper.scss';
```

Comment: Or even better: `import 'swiper/swiper.min.css'`: it's already minified CSS

Comment: This answer fixed it for me, as webpack tried to compile it. The min version in the comment did not.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue. As a result, I'm forced to drop to `6.8.4`.
To begin, uninstall the most recent version of swiper js.

```
npm uninstall swiper
```

then install

```
npm install swiper@6.8.4
```

Then replace

```
// swiper bundle styles
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css'

// swiper core styles
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css'

// modules styles
import 'swiper/components/navigation/navigation.min.css'
import 'swiper/components/pagination/pagination.min.css'
```

Comment: I tried so many solutions by now, but only this one worked, thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

How I solved swipe css module not found problem for version:^8.2.1
If you look at swipe's package.json into node_modules you'll see

```js
  "exports": {
    "./css": "./swiper.min.css",
    "./css/bundle": "./swiper-bundle.min.css",
   }
```

You have to import the css file or css bundle by calling

import 'swipe/css';
import 'swipe/css/bundle';

Comment: This is the correct anwser, you need to check the package.json for what is exportable and how.

Answer (score 3):

In recent versions of Swiper, there is no longer a css folder.
So... to put it simply: swiper/css no longer exists.

But the scss file is available so you can simply adapt your import in this way
import 'swiper/swiper.scss';

Of course as you are on React you will also need the node-sass library

Answer (score 3):

Replace it with
`import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react/swiper-react"; import "swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css";`

Answer (score 2):

By default Swiper exports only core version without additional modules (like Navigation, Pagination, etc.). So you need to import and configure them too:

```
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
```

If you want to import Swiper with all modules (bundle) then it should be imported from swiper/bundle:

```
import Swiper from 'swiper/bundle';
import 'swiper/css/bundle';
```

[Checkout the swipper docs](https://swiperjs.com/get-started)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `version ^8.1.4`. Cause it was imported in the wrong direction in the package, the docs might be doesn't update yet.
You can use like this.

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react/swiper-react";
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css";
import "swiper/swiper.min.css";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Swiper with create-react-app, [their docs](https://swiperjs.com/react#usage-with-create-react-app) mention something about imports regarding Swiper & create-react-app.

This is the reason why others have suggested different ways of importing their components when using with React. Thus, this link & their way of importing is all you need to get started.

But do note that they import their `.scss` files so if you're not using `.scss`, then just import their `.min.css` files like they do, replacing with whatever component(s) you use.
For example, what I used was:

```
`
// Styles must use direct files imports
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css'; // core Swiper
import 'swiper/modules/navigation/navigation.min.css'; // Navigation module
import 'swiper/modules/free-mode/free-mode.min.css'; // Pagination module
import 'swiper/modules/thumbs/thumbs.min.css'; // Pagination module`
```

Answer (score 1):

For version **9.0.0**, they changed the export reference in the package.json:

```scss
@import 'swiper/scss';
@import 'swiper/scss/pagination';
@import 'swiper/scss/navigation';
@import 'swiper/scss/a11y';
```

You can see the full list of references [here](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#scss-styles).

Some [IDE will complain about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72353581/webstorm-doesnt-recognize-webpack-css-import-from-npm-package-export), but the code will compile just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ans: `$import "swiper/swiper.min.css"`;

Try this.
if u have to import any css for pagination, effect-coverflow, etc then import like this..

```
import "swiper/modules/pagination/pagination.min.css";
import "swiper/modules/effect-coverflow/effect-coverflow.min.css";
```

"nodemodules/swiper/modules " contains all the styling.

if not solved... then simply got to `nodemodules` and open the `swiper` file then search for `css files` required to import for your project and then `import` them in code

Answer (score 0):

try with one of the following imports

```
import 'swiper/swiper.less';
import 'swiper/swiper.scss';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min/css';
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future that might run into this problem well working with Next.js, I ended up only including this line:

`import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css'`

and removed any specific css imports (in my case, the navigation css). Everything worked great after that.

Answer (score 0):

For those using swiper v8.0.7, just do this:

1. Include `<script src="path/to/swiper.min.js"></script>` in your index.html file.
2. Include `import "swiper/css"` in your JSX/TSX file (assuming you are using react) file.
3. Viola!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Swiper `v9.x` and saw it control what exports from `package.json`, like below:

```
"exports": {
    ".": "./swiper.esm.js",
    "./core": "./swiper.esm.js",
    "./swiper.esm.js": "./swiper.esm.js",
    "./bundle": "./swiper-bundle.esm.js",
    "./swiper-bundle.esm.js": "./swiper-bundle.esm.js",
    "./css": "./swiper.min.css",
    "./swiper.min.css": "./swiper.min.css",
    "./swiper.css": "./swiper.css",
    "./css/bundle": "./swiper-bundle.min.css",
    "./swiper-bundle.min.css": "./swiper-bundle.min.css",
    "./swiper-bundle.css": "./swiper-bundle.css",
    ...
}
```

you can try upgrade Swiper version and try again, may this help you :)

Answer (score 0):

## 2023 / `NextJs` error screen. Module not found. `Swiper`

In my case the `NextJs` error screen says:

```
Module not found: Package path ./modules/pagination/pagination.min.css is not exported from package \node_modules\swiper (see exports field in \node_modules\swiper\package.json)
```

So, if you look at the `node_modules\swiper\package.json` file, you will see various exports. For example, in my case I tried to import:

```js
import 'swiper/modules/navigation/navigation.min.css';
```

And I found a suitable export in the `node_modules\swiper\package.json`:

```json
{
  /* ... */
  "exports": {
    /* ... */
    "./css/navigation": "./modules/navigation/navigation.min.css",
    /* ... */
  },
  /* ... */
}
```

So I changed my `import` like this:

```js
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
```

Now everything is ok.

Answer (score -1):

import 'swiper/swiper.scss'; this way will help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30762818)