# Nextjs Module not found: Package path Swiper scss

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

There was an error using the swiper in Nextjs.

"next": "^11.1.2",
"swiper": "^7.0.5"

I'm using the version and couldn't get the swiper.scss. I want to know how to solve the issue.

Module not found: Package path ./swiper.scss is not exported from package

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEGpw.png)

Answer (score 13):

I solved this problem.

In that version

```
import 'swiper/scss'
import 'swiper/scss/navigation'
import 'swiper/scss/pagination'
```

You should use it like this.

Comment: it's correct answer

Comment: It is not getting added in the build css chunk, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with `NextJs` and [posted my answer in another stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76976826/14140292). Try it, maybe it will help solve the problem.