# WebStorm doesn't recognize webpack css import from npm package export

Tags: css, npm, webpack, phpstorm, webstorm

I updated some webpack stuff and now they expect imports using the npm packages exports.

New syntax is:

[image]

Old syntax:

[image]

It is expecting you to use imports from the swiper node modules package.json export field here:

[image]

**Question:**

How to get WebStorm/PhpStorm to recognize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Package exports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/package-exports/) are not yet supported in CSS/SASS, please vote for [WEB-55017](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55017) to be notified on any progress with this feature