# Can´t import Swiper Scss in Ionic / Angular App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass

I installed Swiper `npm install swiper`. If I want to add Swiper Scss in the Global SCSS like described here https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/slides I get a Error Message
`./src/global.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): [ng] SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import. [ng]    ╷ [ng] 30 │ @import '~swiper/scss'; [ng]    │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [ng]    ╵ [ng]   src/global.scss 30:9  root stylesheet [ng]  [ng] ./src/global.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js): [ng] HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): [ng] SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import`
I also tried removing the Package and installing it afterwards. It did not help. The topic [Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/css'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69154197/module-not-found-cant-resolve-swiper-css) is simular, but it uses React and CSS. Does someone know how to fix this?

The keyboard folder is empty for example
[image]

I expected, I can add the SCSS file in the Global SCSS and then try out those custom animations

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/slides here is doc you can read for your reference.

Comment: yes i know...but as I described it can´t find the scss files

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 2):

I can see you are trying to import `~swiper/scss`, but when you actually go into the package you can see there is no file like that... that's why the compiler is complaining.

I think there is a mistake in the documentation.

This worked for me (for Ionic 6):

```
@import '~swiper/swiper.min.css';
@import '~@ionic/angular/css/ionic-swiper.css';
```

This first import might not be necessary, but I'm not sure. Maybe someone more experienced can give some definitive answer.